# javassist.NotFoundException since Java 9

Tags: java, javafx, javassist

JavaFX doesn't allow WebViews to be transparent, so I found [this patch](https://gist.github.com/riccardobl/18603f9de508b1ab6c9e) which uses javassist to modify Java's `com.sun.webkit.WebPage`.

This worked fine until Java 8, but stopped working with Java 9:

```
> Patching com/sun/webkit/WebPage ...
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRectangle
    at javassist.CtBehavior.setBody(CtBehavior.java:446)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.setBody(CtBehavior.java:412)
    at com.github.micheljung.transparentwebview.TransparentWebViewPatch.transform(TransparentWebViewPatch.java:64)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:550)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1099)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<clinit>(WebEngine.java:338)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:260)
    at com.github.micheljung.transparentwebview.Demo.start(Demo.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: compile error: no such class: com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRectangle
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.searchImports(MemberResolver.java:468)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClass(MemberResolver.java:412)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupClassByName(MemberResolver.java:315)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atNewExpr(TypeChecker.java:146)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.NewExpr.accept(NewExpr.java:73)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMethodArgs(JvstTypeChecker.java:221)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:735)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:695)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodBody(CodeGen.java:292)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileBody(Javac.java:223)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.setBody(CtBehavior.java:438)
    ... 25 more
/!\ com/sun/webkit/WebPage patching failed :(
javassist.NotFoundException: com.sun.webkit.graphics.WCRectangle
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
    at com.github.micheljung.transparentwebview.TransparentWebViewPatch.transform(TransparentWebViewPatch.java:84)
    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:550)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1099)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<clinit>(WebEngine.java:342)
    at javafx.web/javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:260)
    at com.github.micheljung.transparentwebview.Demo.start(Demo.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
> Patching com/sun/javafx/webkit/prism/WCGraphicsPrismContext ...
/!\ com/sun/javafx/webkit/prism/WCGraphicsPrismContext patching failed :(
```

Since I don't understand how javassist looks for classes, I'm lost here. I assume it has something to do with Java 9 modules. Does anyone know?
The class still exists with the same package name.

[Demo Application for Java 8](https://github.com/micheljung/javafx-transparent-webview-patch/tree/java8)

[Demo Application for Java 9](https://github.com/micheljung/javafx-transparent-webview-patch/tree/java9)

Comment: In your both your demos you're using version 3.20.0-GA of javassist. However, looking at their releases it wasn't until [3.22.0-GA](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/tag/rel_3_22_0_ga) that the library became compatible with Java 9. Also, their latest release is currently [3.23.1-GA](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/tag/rel_3_23_1_ga).

Comment: Oh dear... I feel so dumb. Updating actually solves the problem :) Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Even more embarrassing, I *already had* it updated in my project but I never rebuilt the agent JAR file xD So I thought it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of *javassist* in both your demos: 3.20.0-GA.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA'
}
```

This will work for Java 8 but not for Java 9. If you look at their [releases](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases) page on GitHub it wasn't until version [3.22.0-GA](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/tag/rel_3_22_0_ga) that the library became compatible with Java 9. That version is also outdated, however, as their latest version (as of writing this answer) is [3.23.1-GA](https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/releases/tag/rel_3_23_1_ga).

Change your dependency declaration to use the latest version and your issue should be solved.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.23.1-GA'
}
```

---

Unrelated to your question: I don't know what version of Gradle you're using but in later versions the `compile` configuration is deprecated; it has been superseded by `implementation`. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) for more information.